# ¿Por qué un parámetro se comporta como función?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript

Intenté hacer algo parecido a esto pero ya con datos asignados previamente a un array ahora esta no me funciona tuve que imprimir por consola var.

Aquí por ejemplo ejemplo  para imprimir el arreglo es por medio del parámetro func();yo no sabia que se podía ejecutar como si fuera una función, conozco mas de lenguaje strictos como java

```js
var funcions = [];

for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
  funcions.push(function() {
    console.log(x);
  });
}

funcions.forEach(
  function(func) {
    func();
  }
);
```

Aquí intente hacerlo de otra manera pero ya no funciono igual alguien sabe por que?

```js
   [1,6666,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"mombre"].forEach((va)=>{

va();
});
```

```js
   [1,6666,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"mombre"].forEach((va)=>{

console.log(va);
});
```

Alguien sabe dónde obtener más información para entender su funcionamiento interno

Comment: Hola Rene Israel Ibarra, esta pregunta no termina de quedar muy clara. Sería ideal que editaras la publicación para añadir más detalles (p.e. qué es lo que intentas hacer con ese código, qué es lo que está fallando o no funciona como esperas, o qué información es la que necesitas). Lee [ask] para más información. Y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio.

Comment: No es me da un problema solo quiero entender ese comportamiento

Comment: Quizás se me escapa algo, pero el array que tienes (el del `forEach`) es un array de funciones, por lo tanto el parámetro que estás pasando es una función, y se comporta de la forma esperada.

Comment: @ReneIsraelIbarra pero tu codigo esta insertando en el arreglo una funcion, y eso es lo que obtendras

Answer (score 1):

Porque en el segundo caso estas utilizando la funcion foreach que recibe como primer argumento el elemento que itera sobre el array.

Es decir, `va`, es uno de los elementos de tu array. Tu tercer ejemplo es el analogo a tu primer ejemplo.

Si te fijas, va es de tipo `number`, no `function`, por lo tanto no puedes ejecutar `va();`

```js
[1,6666,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"mombre"].forEach((va)=>{

console.log(typeof va);
});
```

Fijate en la documentacion de foreach: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach

Lo que si admite foreach es una funcion callback que se ejecutara por cada elemento (en mi ejemplo la funcion `printValue`):

```js
const printValue = (va) => console.log(va);

[1,6666,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"mombre"].forEach(printValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

me parece que estas confundiendo las cosas, para entender vamos a tener que ir por partes.

```js
// Este array soporta todo tipo de 
// valores, string, number, function, object.
var funcions = []; 

for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
  // aquí estas agregando funciones
  // functions.push(x), si pusheas de esta manera serían valores
  // y no funciones 
  funcions.push(function() { 
    console.log(x);
  });
}

// aquí estas iterando las funciones que antes agregaste
funcions.forEach( 
  // "func" es el nombre que le pones al valor de tu array,
  // puede ser cualquier nombre, ejem. item, a, b, value, etc.
  function(func) { 
    //como tu agregaste puras funciones, esta te devuelve
    // funciones y las estas ejecutando y por eso te muestran los console log
    func();  
  }
);
```

En el siguiente ejemplo espero explicarme mejor

```js
// estoy agregando varios tipos de valores
var List = [
  function(){ return 'soy una funcion' }, 
  "soy una cadena", 
  123, 
  {nombre: "waldo"}
]

// los array tiene varias maneras de iterar y 
// el forEach es una de ellas, y como primer parametro es una función con argumentos valor, indice.
//
List.forEach(function(item, indice){
  console.log(indice, typeof item, item)
  // retorna
  
  // 0 function  function (){ return 'soy una funcion' }
  // 1 string soy una cadena 
  // 2 number 123
  // 3 object { "nombre": "waldo" }
  
})
```

En este ejemplo, solo cambias el arrow function, en la nueva versión de js que es el 2015, se agrego el "arrow function" que no es necesario agregar la palabra reservada "function" solo "() => {}" y su principal beneficio es que no encierra su propio contexto como lo hace "function".

```js
   [1,6666,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"mombre"].forEach((va)=>{

console.log(va);
});
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En tu primer ejemplo estas agregando funciones como miembros de tu array, pero en los otros ejemplos los miembros de los arrays son literales.

Cuando asignas un primitivo u objeto a  una variable, si llamas esta variable sin paréntesis te devolverá el objeto al que hace referencia la variable, pero si llamas a la variable con paréntesis, primero se revisa que el primitivo u objeto llamado sea una función, si no es una función, lo cual es lo que pasa en el segundo ejemplo, te devuelve error, pero si es una función, te devolve el resultado de la ejecución de la función llamada.

Tal vez resulte mas sencillo verlo en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
var funcion = function(){return prompt('¿Cómo te llamas?')};

console.info(funcion) // Imprimirá en la consola la función
console.info(funcion()); // Imprimirá en la consola el valor capturado por el usuario
```